# Replace next line after match in perl

Tags: perl

All the searches I have made give me answers in sed or awk, but I want the pure perl solution.
I the text below I want to modify the next line after a match.

```
opts@FieldTitle = "mcape"
opts@MainTitle  = "MCAPE: NODA~C~Valid:" + dystr(it) + "/" + mnstr(it) + "/" + yrstr(it) + "Issued:" + dystr(0) + "/" + mnstr(0) + "/" + yrstr(0)
opts@ContourParameters = (/ 500., 3000., 250./)

opts@FieldTitle = "mcin"
opts@MainTitle  = "MCIN: NODA~C~Valid:" + dystr(it) + "/" + mnstr(it) + "/" + yrstr(it) + "Issued:" + dystr(0) + "/" + mnstr(0) + "/" + yrstr(0)
opts@ContourParameters = (/ 0., 125., 25./)
```

I read the whole file at once with

```
@scrptlines=<$NCLSCRPT>;
```

Then I have other replacements to make with

```
foreach $scrptlines (@scrptlines){
$scrptlines =~ s/DATADir =.*/DATADir = "$INPUT_DIR[$kk]\/"/g; #e.g.
```

When I come to the above lines, I have tried

```
if($scrptlines =~ m/opts\@FieldTitle = "mcape"/){
next unless($scrptlines =~ m/opts\@MainTitle/);
$scrptlines =~ s/opts\@MainTitle  =.*/opts\@MainTitle  = "MCIN: NODA~C~Valid:" + dystr(it) + "\/" + mnstr(it) + "\/" + yrstr(it) + "Issued:" + dystr(0) + "\/" + mnstr(0) + "\/" + yrstr(0)/;
}
```

Then tried

```
    if($scrptlines =~ m/opts\@FieldTitle = "mcape"/){
$scrptlines =~/opts@FieldTitle = "mcape"/{n;s\/opts\@MainTitle  =.*/opts@MainTitle  = "MCIN: NODA~C~Valid:" + dystr(it) + "\/" + mnstr(it) + "\/" + yrstr(it) + "Issued:" + dystr(0) + "\/" + mnstr(0) + "\/" + yrstr(0)/};
```

Both don't work, plus other tries I made.

Comment: What is the line after which youo want to make changes -- "_opts@FieldTitle = "mcape"_" ... that one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a "flag" (variable) to true when the line is matched, otherwise keep it false.  Then you can make needed changes if that flag is true, what will be in the next iteration after it's been set, so for the next line from the file.

```
my $saw_trigger_line;

foreach my $line (@scrptlines) { 
    if ($saw_trigger_line) { 
        # Do what is needed
        # If it's all done then unset the flag for the future operation
        $saw_trigger_line = 0;
    }

    ...

    # Sets the flag to true if line matches
    $saw_trigger_line = $line =~ /opts\@FieldTitle = "mcape"/;
}
```

The flag can be set by assigning to it the return value of the regex's match operator, because the operator itself (the expression `$var =~ /.../`) returns true or false (normally `1` or `''`).

We need to first test the flag (and do what is needed if true), so to see whether it was set in *the previous iteration*, and only later in the loop reevaluate it (set or unset again).  For this we can set the flag by the end of the loop so it will have that value in the next iteration.

Comment: I have to take time to understand this. I will come back to you

Comment: @ZiloreMumba  I added a comment, and edited a little for clarity.  I am happy to edit/clarify more if you let me know what needs more/better explanaiton